# Configure and install Intellij IDEA SDK

Tags: intellij-idea

Now I want to write a plugin in intellij , development of every custom plugins requires the IntelliJ IDEA SDK to be installed and configured for that project. How can I install and configure sdk to my project?

Answer (score 0):

[Here you](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Getting+Started+with+Plugin+Development#GettingStartedwithPluginDevelopment-anchor2) can read official guide to configure IntelliJ Idea SDK

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. In the Project Structure dialog box that opens, do the following, and then click OK
3. Under Platform Settings, click SDKs, and then click the plus sign icon.
   From the provided list, select IntelliJ IDEA Plugin SDK.
4. Using the Select Path dialog box that opens, select the IntelliJ IDEA installation directory directory, and then click OK. Note, that by default, this dialog box automatically selects the home directory of the currently running IntelliJ IDEA installation.
5. In the Select internal Java platform dialog box that opens, select a Java SDK (JDK 1.6 is recommended) to be used as IDEA internal platform, and then click OK.
6. Optionally, in Sandbox Home, change the default folder to which Intellij IDEA will copy plugins for debugging.
7. Open the Sourcepath tab, click Add, and then select the folder where you have checked out the sources of IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.
8. In the Detected Source Roots dialog box that opens, click OK.